# How to convert text from one character set to another?

Tags: python, character-encoding

i have following problem:
i need to convert this text: "test+%2B%C4%8D%C5%A5%C5%BE%C3%BD" to this "test +čťžý"
i can do it online using this website : https://2cyr.com/decode/ on the website it says that the source text is in "WINDOWS-1251" character set and i need it to be in is "UTF-8".

in other words, i need to see the accented characters like this "čšť" not like this "%2B%C4"
how can i achieve this? i tried to google it but none of the solutions i found help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `unquote` from Python's urllib will convert these characters from their %XX escaped forms back into UTF-8. Documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote

```
>>> from urllib.parse import unquote
>>> unquote('test+%2B%C4%8D%C5%A5%C5%BE%C3%BD')
'test++čťžý'
```

Comment: Technically `unquote` converts the characters to *unicode*, not UTF-8, because it returns a `str`, not `bytes`.